# How to increase row Height on button tapp action inside the cell in swift 2

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, xcode7

I am new to swift, I have a table row containing 2 labels(Name and Description) and a button to the right side. On button click I want to display some controls at the bottom of description.

I am using self sizing technique to fit the content in the row dynamically, by using following code.

```
tableView.rowHeight = IUTableViewAutomaticDimension
```

My description text is multi line(depending on the text 1 to 5) data is showing in my table view just fine. But on button tapped row height is not increasing as automatically. Following is the code in button tapped.

```
lblmoreDescrption.hidden = false
```

I am using Xcode 7 with swift 2.

Thanks

Comment: what about just reloading cell ?

Comment: Thanks @ogres, button action is handled inside my tableViewCell how can   I call tableview's reloadRowsAtIndexPath?

Comment: set delegate to the cell from the outside ( where you are creating the cell ) and when the button is tapped call the delegate that button was tapped and then just reload it

Comment: this is what i am thinking to do. But is there any other appropriate/default way?

Comment: that is the appropriate way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this :

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Where `indexPath` is the index path of the cell you want to re-load.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift:

```
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
    tableView.endUpdates()
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please assign tag to button which you have add in `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexpath indexPath:`

And in button click event, do like :

```
@IBAction func buttonClick(sender:UIButton!) {

    self.tblName.beginUpdates()
    self.tblName.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)]) , withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
    self.tblName.endUpdates()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on button click after doing changes. You can convert this objective c code to swift.

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your controls inside one UIView and you can take iboutlet for that uiview's height constraint. And you need to set it 0 as prior and when clicked on the Button inside the cell, You need to make it as appropriate height and then reload that rows at indexpath.

For Example.

```
    Iboutlet UIVIEW *viewCustomControls; // This contains your extra controls which you want to show on the button clicked.
   Iboutlet NSLayoutConstraints *cons_height_viewControl; // This is the constraint outlet for the viewCustomControls Height.
```

When you clicked on the button inside your clicked event...

```
{
if (need to expands)
{
      cons_height_viewControl.constants = 100 // To expand, Here is approximate value you can make as you want.
}else{
      cons_height_viewControl.constants = 0 // To collapse
    }
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(arrIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```